# Python fillna using mean of row values for selected columns

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

In the below table I need to only fillna for Week columns. NaN should be filled with mean value of all weeks in that row.

```
+----+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | Feature | Paid | Week1 | Week2 | Week3 | Week4 |
+----+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1  | 1       | 1    | 12    | NaN   | NaN   | NaN   |   
+----+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2  | 0       | 1    | 34    | 23    | NaN   | NaN   |
+----+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 3  | 1       | 0    | 24    | 13    | 14    | NaN   |
+----+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**Code**

```
df.fillna(df[[Week1,Week2,Week3,Week4]].mean(axis=1),axis=1,inplace=True)
```

This gives an error saying `NotImplementedError: Currently only can fill with dict/Series column by column`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try via `filter()` select columns Named like 'Week' then find mean and store that into a variable(for good performance) and finally fill `NaN's` by using `fillna()`:

```
cols=df.filter(regex='Week').columns
m=df[cols].mean(axis=1).round()
df=df.fillna({x:m for x in cols})
```

output:

```
    ID  Feature Paid    Week1       Week2   Week3   Week4
0   1       1       1       12      12.0    12.0    12.0
1   2       0       1       34      23.0    28.0    28.0
2   3       1       0       24      13.0    14.0    17.0
```

Comment: is it possible to round the mean value?

Comment: @shockwave yes kindly check update **:)**

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary that maps the `Week` names to the `mean` values of weeks along `axis=1`, then fill the `NaN` values using this dictionary

```
c = df.filter(like='Week').columns
df.fillna(dict.fromkeys(c, df[c].mean(1)))
```

---

```
   ID  Feature  Paid  Week1  Week2  Week3  Week4
0   1        1     1     12   12.0   12.0   12.0
1   2        0     1     34   23.0   28.5   28.5
2   3        1     0     24   13.0   14.0   17.0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `SimpleImputer` from `scikit-learn` with `strategy='mean'` in this function you have `strategy='most_frequent'` also and use this is easy.[(doc)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, np.NaN, 1, 2], "B": [1,2, 3, 4, 5], "C":[np.NaN, 3, 4, np.NaN, 5]})

imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imp.fit(df)
print(imp.transform(df))
```

output:

```
[[1.  1.  4. ]
 [2.  2.  3. ]
 [1.5 3.  4. ]
 [1.  4.  4. ]
 [2.  5.  5. ]]
```

for example for `strategy='most_frequent'` you have:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, np.NaN, 1, 2], "B": [1,2, 3, 4, 5], "C":[np.NaN, 3, 4, np.NaN, 5]})

imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')
imp.fit(df)
print(imp.transform(df))
```

output:

```
[[1. 1. 3.]
 [2. 2. 3.]
 [1. 3. 4.]
 [1. 4. 3.]
 [2. 5. 5.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
cols=['Week1','Week2','Week3','Week4']
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(0) + df[cols].isna().mul(df[cols].mean(axis=1),axis=0)
df
Out[87]: 
   ID  Feature  Paid  Week1  Week2  Week3  Week4
0   1        1     1   12.0   12.0   12.0   12.0
1   2        0     1   34.0   23.0   28.5   28.5
2   3        1     0   24.0   13.0   14.0   17.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, np.NaN, 1, 2], "B": [1,2, 3, 4, 5], "C":[np.NaN, 3, 4, np.NaN, 5]})
cols=["A", "C"]
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(df[cols].mean())
     A  B    C
0  1.0  1  4.0
1  2.0  2  3.0
2  1.5  3  4.0
3  1.0  4  4.0
4  2.0  5  5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to overcome the error is to transpose before/after filling Nas:

```
df.T.fillna(df.filter(like='Week').mean(axis=1)).T.astype(int)
```

output:

```
   ID  Feature  Paid  Week1  Week2  Week3  Week4
0   1        1     1     12     12     12     12
1   2        0     1     34     23     28     28
2   3        1     0     24     13     14     17
```